# Python os.environ unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, ubuntu, variables, environment

I'm trying to set environment variable in Ubuntu, just like:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from os import environ, getenv, _exit
mykey = str(uuid4())
environ['mykey'] =  mykey
getkey = environ['mykey']
assert getkey == mykey
```

And, of course, `getkey` equals `mykey`. But when I run another script:

```
from os import environ, getenv
getkey = environ.get('mykey', None)
print(getkey)
getkey = getenv('mykey', None)
print(getkey)
```

I unexpectedly get None from environ, and also None from getenv().
What should I do to set environment variable visible for any python script?

Comment: You can't modify the environment of a process from its child. Changes in one script are not visible to another. That's why things like `.bash_profile` are *sourced*, not executed, and why you often see programs that output shell code intended to be executed with `eval` (e.g., `ssh-agent`).

Comment: Additions to `environ`, like you do in the 1st example, are preserved for the current Python session only. So when you run a different script, the default parent environment variables are inherited.